# Running Rdevtool::test_that on buffer save in ESS

Tags: r, emacs, devtools, ess, testthat

My workflow:

- Hack away at an .R or test_*.R file
- Save buffer.
- Switch to window with *R* process
- hit C-p, RET. to re-evaluate `devtools::test()`

To me, this seems far too arduous.  Why can't I get R to run `devtools::test()` automatically when I save the buffer? Please help, my fingers can barely take the strain of the seven extra keystrokes!

Comment: I have opened a new issue for devtools integration [here](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/229).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for a similar setup (switching to a `shell` buffer):

```
(defun devtools-test ()
  (interactive)
  (when (string-match (rx-to-string `(: ".R" eos) t) (buffer-name))
    (switch-to-buffer "*R*")
    (end-of-buffer)
    (insert "devtools::test()")
    (comint-send-input)))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'devtools-test)
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Not quite.  Your function switches my current buffer to the R process; I'd like for that to stay where it is, in another window in the same frame where I view the output.  Your function is an improvement, but since I am  forced to switch back to the  file bufffer after the tests have run, I still feel I'm facing too much hardship.
I think if there was an insert-into-buffer function that could get text into *R* without switching, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: It's easier to just switch back to the old buffer:
`(when ...
    (let* ((old (current-buffer)))
      (switch-to-buffer "*R") ... (switch-to-buffer old))))`

Sorry I can't format it properly in this comment.

Comment: Yes!  That really does the trick. Here's a gist of the final product:
https://gist.github.com/Momus/7e7738971923d0c91555

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, there are easier way to do this in recent versions of ESS.

The function/command `ess-r-devtools-test` now runs `devtools::test`.

So you could achieve this with (untested):

```
(add-hook 'ess-r-mode-hook 
          (lambda () 
             (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'devtools-test nil 'local)))
```

In addition, there are many other useful functions under `ess-r-devtools-*` for build, install etc.

It's worth noting that calling `ess-r-devtools-test` with the universal argument will filter tests by the current file.

So calling `C-u M-x ess-r-devtools` from a file `my-file.R` will run `devtools::test(filter="my-file")`.

This can be useful to bear in mind when choosing names for test files, or when rerunning only the current test file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `ess-eval-linewise` function which you can use.

Something like this (not tested):

```
(defun devtools-test ()
  (interactive)
  (when (and (equal ess-dialect "R")
             (string-match "^test.*\\.[Rr]$" (buffer-name)))
    (ess-eval-linewise "devtools::test()")))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'devtools-test)
```

I would not recommend this though, as for some packages tests take quite a while to run. You don't want them running on every save.

There will be a dedicated `devtools` functionality in ess soon. Follow this [issue](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/229).